# GAS x86 Assembly Serial port hangs

Tags: assembly, x86

Below is my code for trying to practice my assembly language skills.  I am writing part of the unix/linux echo function in assembly.  My issue is whenever i input a character it just hangs and never gives back the output.  I am fairly new to programming in assembly.  If anyone has any pointers it would be much appreciated.

I expect the function to take in a comport address and the escape character.  If i enter in a random letter on the screen it should reply with that same letter.  Here is the code:

```
   #function call is echo(conport,escape)
#LSR byte is plus 5
#TX and RX are plus 0
.text
.globl _echo

_echo:
        pushl %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp

        movl 8(%ebp), %edx #grab the comport int
        movb 12(%ebp), %bl #grab the special escape character
        movl %edx, %ecx #copies the comport int address
        addl $5, %edx  #gets me to lsr
loop:
        inb (%dx), %al #reads in  the lsr byte
        andb $1, %al #isolates the DR bit 
        jz loop
ready:
        movl %ecx, %edx #set back edx
        inb (%dx), %al
        cmpb %al, %bl
        je end
        outb %al, (%dx)
        addl $5, %edx #get to lsr for loop
        jmp loop

end:
        movl %ebp, %esp
        popl %ebp
        ret
        .end
```

I updated the code above.  I can now get a return but it runs in an endless loop instead of just coming back once and setting up a new line.

UPDATE 2:To clarify the update more i should be able to type in a letter and receive the letter back.  instead as soon as i hit b i get bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.....which runs on forever. I am trying to figure out my logic issues as to why i have this endless loop.

UPDATE3: updated the code.  I get no output now but it doesn't take off like it used to. It will write a bunch of characters and then if i press enter it will go to the beginning of the line and start to write over them.  I know it takes in an input because as soon as i press the escape character it ends.

Comment: Your test for whether an input byte is available is backwards. You also need to to test for whether the output byte buffer is available.

Comment: Would that be checked right before the outb statement?

Comment: Yes, since you're checking to see if it OK to execute that statement. The behaviour you noticed when you press the enter key is expected. It sends the ASCII carriage return character (CR, 13) which when echoed back to the terminal cause it move the cursor back to the beginning of the line. If you want it to advance to the next line you also need to echo back a line feed character (LF, 10).

Comment: AH that makes perfect sense when you type it out like that! thanks